# Mysql : assign integer value to the String values and get the average

Tags: mysql

I am using mysql database. i have a table called feedback which has a field **howIsTraining**
which may have one value out five values "Excellent, Very Good, Good, Poor and Pathetic"

i want to write the query which will give average of this value from all the data in following format

I want give integer value to each of the values

Excellent = 5 
Very Good = 4
Good      = 3 
Poor      = 2
Pathetic  = 1

if say i have five records in table Excellent,Very Good,Excellent,Good, Poor 
that means **((5+4+5+3+2)/5) = 3.8**

**finally it will give result as 3.8**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select avg(case howIsTraining
             when 'Excellent' then 5
             when 'Very Good' then 4
             when 'Good' then 3
             when 'Poor' then 2
             when 'Pathetic' then 1
             else null
           end) as avg_rating
from feedback
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/14a06/1

But you should **really** think about a better design (e.g. as shown by Jack)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have another table that keeps the scores:

```
scores
----------+------
term      | value
----------+------
Excellent | 5
Very Good | 4
...
```

Then you would have a query such as this:

```
SELECT AVG(scores.value)
FROM feedback
INNER JOIN scores ON term = howIsTraining;
```

Comment: is it not possible in that single table .. i.e not having another table?

Comment: @maaz Yes, you can use `CASE` for that, but I thought you already had a separate table; in fact, I would recommend it so that you can use referential integrity :)

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it make more sense to have integer column in database with values from 1 to 5. And then when representing data you convert the number to string?

In extreme case add extra integer column and populate it with correct grade values by UPDATE... SET grade=1 where hoIsTraing='Pathetic'.

Comment: Everything can be changed.

Comment: but i want those values to remain in that format itself.. is it not doable(like i said above) in mysql...?